# How does Raspberry Pi get its IP through DHCP?

Tags: raspbian, networking, dhcp

How does a Raspberry Pi send a DHCP request on startup? I have a hunch that it is through the program dhcpcd, if so, is it possible to disable dhcpcd and instead have dhclient run as the default DHCP client? Thank you for any insights.

Comment: Why do you want to use dhclient instead?

Comment: I have a modified configuration file for dhclient that has a couple of specified dhcp options I wanted to test.